# How to get numeric and string value from excel file cell, using POI , i am getting error for numeric value, string value easily fetch

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Currently i am using `String data= sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();`
It works properly for String value but displays error for numeric value.
So i have to add numeric value like "34567" in excel.
Is there any other method to fetch both numeric and String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an error when you try to fetch the numeric cell as String.

You should be setting the cellType as string like below, before fetching the numeric cell.

```
   HSSFCell yourCell = sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column);
   yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
   String data = yourCell.getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot vijay .. it works for me .. :) Appreciate your knowledge :) @vijay

Answer (score 0):

in the template excel change the column type as string.then get the value as string as follows sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue().Then pasrse to integer or whatever.